# Respuesta SQL Server 2017 lenta en remoto (1mbps), rápida en LAN (30-40Mbps)

Tags: sql-server, optimización

Llevo semanas haciendo todo tipo de pruebas para intentar averiguar por qué cuando una aplicación cliente accede al servidor *SQL Server* en *LAN*. Todo funciona como un tiro (*20-40Mbps*), y sin embargo la misma aplicación accediendo en remoto a esa misma base de datos no puede alcanzar una velocidad de respuesta de más de *1-2Mbps*.

Premisas:

1. Realizado las pruebas de velocidad de la fibra en ambos extremos de 600/600.
2. Puertos abiertos 1433 y 1434 *UDP/TCP*. Latencia 10ms
3. *SQL Browser* iniciado.
4. Aplicación cliente utiliza *Sqlclient64bits* y funciona perfecto en *LAN*.
5. Una consulta que tarda 6 segundos en *LAN* lleva aproximadamente 30 segundos en remoto.

Quisiera que las consultas se ejecuten a una velocidad aceptable en internet en remoto.

¿Existe algun tipo de parámetro en *SQL Server* que tenga que configurar para poder gestionar las consultas en remoto (por internet) con fluidez?

Comment: Probaste hacer un test de velocidad en tu servidor(donde tienes la db)? Que velocidad tienes contratada?

Comment: hola, Si. He puesto en las premisas de mi consulta que el test de velocidad movistar es correcto. 600 de bajada y 600 de subida en ambos extremos. Tengo la sensación que debe ser algo de parametrización del SQL Server 2017 Express para consultas que vienen por Internet desde el remoto.....pero la verdad que no lo controlo mucho.

Comment: Tendrás que utilizar el analizador de rendimiento (profiler) para revisar qué consultas lanza exactamente tu aplicación y comparar las diferencias (tiempos) entre LAN y Remoto.
Yo creo que el problema puede ser que lance muchas consultas pequeñas, como la latencia en LAN es baja te va rápido pero en remoto... suele ir infinitamente más lento.
Si es eso, cambia tu aplicación para que lance el mínimo número de consultas posible.

Comment: Efectivamente!! Nunca he utilizado el profiler ya que no soy un experto en SQL SERVER, y por lo que he podido observar, efectivamente la aplicación lanza muchas consultas pequeñas por lo que si le añadimos el efecto de la latencia tiene toda la pinta de que estés en lo cierto. Lamentablemente no puedo cambiar de aplicación por lo que me veo obligado a instalar el cliente y el servidor en la misma LAN (o en el mismo equipo), y poder dar acceso por RDP a los usuarios remotos.... en fin.... te agradezco mucho que me hayas orientado sobre la posible causa del problema.

Comment: Nota: El caso en concreto era abrir una reserva de hotel en la que la duración de la estancia es de 30 días. Las consultas ejecutadas en total han sido 150 aprox. por lo que puedo intuir que por cada día de estancia la aplicación ejecutaba una media de 5 querys.... quizá esta aplicación no ha sido diseñada todo lo bien que debería.

Comment: Quizás no me he enterado bien del problema, pero si tu servidor se conecta a tu base de datos, la latencia entre ambos debería ser la misma independientemente de que te conectases desde el mismo equipo o uno remoto. ¿Cómo se están realizando las consultas? ¿La lógica/peticiones están en el cliente?